# Django Celery beat crashes on start

Tags: django, celery

I have recently configured a new server with RabbitMQ and Celery. When I try to start Celerybeat on the machine it starts for a few seconds and stops. I have given right permissions to the log files and changed the owners to the Application user. I have also checked the celerybeat.log file and NO errors are registered.

I tried to start it this way in the project folder:

```
./manage.py celerybeat
```

And I got this error:

```
[2010-12-01 09:59:46,127: INFO/MainProcess] process shutting down
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do in my opinion and launch it for show you all the output in console and by using the base command celeryd.
Try

```
python manage.py celeryd -B -l DEBUG
```

I know that a recent update of celery have problem with log files if you launch it with an old version of python (less than 2.6).